# Mathematica ExtraPackage

Tags: packages, custom-notation, installation

Where can I install the Wolfram ExtraPackages? Especially the `` "Notation`" `` package? I do not seem to have it by default (In the Utilities, I have only two documents, called CleanSlate.m and URLTools.m) and I cannot find any information on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh ok, so after some further reading, it seems that doing:

```
<< Notation`
```

does the trick. I was trying to do something like

```
Needs[Utilities`Notation`]
```

but with no success. I am not very sure where Wolfram takes the package from though?

Comment: I believe the Notation package can be found by calling `SystemOpen[$InstallationDirectory]` and then navigating to the folder AddOns > Packages. These are all preinstalled packages, they just aren't loaded into system memory when Mathematica is opened (presumably to reduce load times and memory usage for typically non-critical packages).

Comment: It is exactly as MassDefect said. You can open the folder directly with `SystemOpen@
 FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Packages", 
   "Notation"}]`.

Comment: and you could have used ```Needs["Notation`"]``` or ```Get["Notation`"]``` just as well. `<<` is just a shortcut for `Get` and will automatically convert its argument into a string. Both `Get` and `Needs` should work and usually `Needs` is the better choice.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily get the path to any installed package file using `FindFile`, for example:

```
FindFile["Notation`"]
```

> ```
> "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\11.3\\AddOns\\Packages\\Notation\\Kernel\\init.m"
> ```

If the package isn't installed, you could search it in several places on the Internet. Don't forget about this site, old [Wolfram Library Archive](http://library.wolfram.com/) and also brand-new [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/).